# Pinescript Strategy - execute Safety orders with different volumes

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write a pinescript strategy and insert a if condition and do something only one time, then in the next turn an all other turns following do somehing different.
My intent is to execute the first safety order with different parameters than all the others.
it doesnt work.

I also tried var i=0

I would appreciate any hint

```
i=0

if (i==0)
   do this only one time
   i=1

else
   now do this
```

Comment: Do you mean only execute something on the first bar? That can be done with `if barstate.isfirst`

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer
No not in the first bar,
I have entered strategy.long and now I want to add a DCA safety order position lets say 1% below the base entry.
All following safety orders should be entered at a different % but therefore I need to tell pinescript its the first DCA and now do this and then its the 2nd safety order now do that. I am having troubles coding these different steps. I thought I would do it with an if-clause but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the code you already have, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Thanks.